# How to debug VS website remotely

Tags: .net, networking, ftp, remote-debugging

I have crated a ftp server and placed my website code over there. Now i want my team members to work on the same copy over internet. Now the problem is that they can open the solution in VS 2008 but could not debug it. i installed remote desktop monitoring and all required setups but could not get what the problem actually is.

1 more Q, if i want someone to access mywebpage remotely thru http://localhost/...
by using my ip address what port do i need to open. Is it 80 or something else as when i debug my page it shows url something like that
http://localhost:**portNo**/mysolution/page.aspx
Here this port no keeps on changing every time, so i cant get that which port has to be opened so as to make it accessible.
as
http://my_ipaddress/solutionName/pageName

I m using windows server 2003/vs.net 3.5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "Web" settings for the webproject you are using the Visual Studio Development Server with Auto-assigned port number. This is why it changes port number. It starts up every time you start to debug. This can be defined to a specified port as well.

Either way you need to open up this port in your firewall settings.

You could also run it under IIS to make sure it runs all the time, not only when debugging (there's an option for this on the settings page).

What is that your team members cannot debug? Do you want to run the site on one machine, and have remote users debug it? If so you need to look into Remote Debugging. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IISRemoteDebugging.aspx) on how to set it up.

Comment: @Mikael Svenson thx for support. Yes my team members currently gets login into my windows server remote desktop connection but i want them to work from their own machine using the same copy of project.
We are working from different different locations. And i tried to configure Remote Debugging and it showed me that it is debugging the code but my friends were not able to run it on their browsers. When they used to update the code from remote location and executes the code, it gets executed but no output is displayed on browser. This is the actual problem